# Issues getting the search feature to find any words in the cell in mvc5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't figure how to make the search feature search by anywords that is the the description field only wants to search by one word or a word that startswith. I remember I used Like in sql command but not sure how to fit it in here.
Kbs Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using _399KB.Models;
using PagedList;

namespace _399KB.Controllers
{
    public class kbsController : Controller
    {
        private kbEntities db = new kbEntities();

        // GET: kbs
        public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search, int? page)
        {


            if
                     (searchBy == "title")
                return View(db.kbs.OrderBy(x => x.title).Where(x => x.title.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));

            if
                    (searchBy == "description")
                return View(db.kbs.OrderBy(x => x.title).Where(x => x.description.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));


            if
                    (searchBy == "keywords")
                return View(db.kbs.OrderBy(x => x.title).Where(x => x.keywords.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));

            if
                  (searchBy == "links")
                return View(db.kbs.OrderBy(x => x.title).Where(x => x.links.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));

            else
            {
                return View(db.kbs.OrderBy(x => x.title).Where(x => x.keywords.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
            }
        }


        // GET: kbs/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            kb kb = db.kbs.Find(id);
            if (kb == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(kb);
        }

        // GET: kbs/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: kbs/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,title,description,keywords,links")] kb kb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.kbs.Add(kb);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(kb);
        }

        // GET: kbs/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            kb kb = db.kbs.Find(id);
            if (kb == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(kb);
        }

        // POST: kbs/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,title,description,keywords,links")] kb kb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(kb).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(kb);
        }

        // GET: kbs/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            kb kb = db.kbs.Find(id);
            if (kb == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(kb);
        }

        // POST: kbs/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            kb kb = db.kbs.Find(id);
            db.kbs.Remove(kb);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

view page

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using _399KB.Models;


@model IPagedList<_399KB.Models.kb>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<hr />


  <!-- ** BEGIN SEARCH AREA ** -->

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title">Search Area</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "kbs/Index", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "keywords", true)<text>keywords</text>
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "title")<text>title </text>
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "description")<text>description </text>
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "links")<text>links</text>

 <div class="panel-body">
     @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { @class = "form-control" })<span class="input-group-btn"></span>
 </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">

                    <button id="btnSearch"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        &nbsp;Search
                    </button>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "kbs")" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        Reset</a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "kbs")" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            Add

                        </a>
</div>


            }
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ** END SEARCH AREA ** -->

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().keywords)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().links)
        </th>
        <th>Modify_KB_Record___</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.keywords)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.links)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.links)</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, searchBy = Request.QueryString["searchBy"], search = Request.QueryString["search"] }),
new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true, DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true })
```

Comment: What does 95% of this code have to do with your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I posted the code because I cannot figure how to set it up in the controller I only started using startwith to see if that worked but not what I wanted. I am new to mvc 5 not understanding how I would implement what i need. and the view has the search function at the top not sure if i need to change something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `StartsWith`, use `Contains`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed